# Distinguishing between Poisson distribution and a similar distribution w/ small mean

Tags: estimation, poisson-distribution, goodness-of-fit

I have an experiment where if all is going well the measured distribution should be Poisson (to very good approximation) with mean $\lambda \sim .1$, but if something goes wrong the distribution will be subtly different.  To make things concrete, there are basically two different types of altered distributions that could crop up:

1. Let's call the probability of $n$ counts in the unperturbed distribution $P_0(\lambda;n)$.  For $n > 0$, the altered distribution is $P_1(n \ge 1) = \alpha P_0(\lambda;n)$ and for $n = 0$ it is $P_1(n=0) = 1 - \alpha(1 - P_0(\lambda;n))$, where $0 \le \alpha \le 1$.  I.e., for all $n>0$, the number of counts should be reduced by a factor of $\alpha$, and the counts in the $n=0$ bin are enhanced.
2. The second altered distribution is one where each independent event is still drawn from a Poisson distribution, but the mean can change slightly for each event, i.e., $P_2(n) = P_0((1-\xi_i)\lambda;n)$, where $\xi_i$ is some small perturbation on the $i^{th}$ independent event. No particular model for the distribution of $\xi_i$ can be assumed.

In both cases, I need to determine a strong limit on the parameters causing the deviation from a pure Poisson distribution.  E.g., in the first case I'd like to be be able to say there is something like a probability of $10^{-6}$ that $1 - \alpha$ is smaller than some threshold value.  In the second case the thing I need to bound is probably the variance of $\xi$.

We know approximately what $\lambda$ will be in our experiment, however it can't be known exactly and so must be treated as a free parameter.  The number of independent events will typically be between 10,000 and 100,000, perhaps larger in some cases.

This seems like some combination of parameter estimation and goodness-of-fit, and I'm a confused physicist in need of some help from the pros!

Comment: Can both happen at the same time? Strong bounds on the second thing may be trickier (or at least much wider) than the first thing. How confident are you about the independence?

Comment: Both couldn't happen at the same time, but either could happen.  I.e., the two cases should be analyzed completely separately.  In all cases, each event is actually certain to be independent (or arbitrarily close to it) due to the underlying physics causing the distributions.